# Find the absolute maximum and minimum of $f(x,y,z)=ax+by+cz$ over the function $h(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ using Lagrange multiplier

Tags: partial-derivative, maxima-minima, lagrange-multiplier

> Find the absolute maximum and minimum of $f(x,y,z)=ax+by+cz$ over the function $h(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ using Lagrange multiplier.

---

$$\mathcal{L}(x,y,z,\lambda)=f(x,y,z)+\lambda g(x,y,z)$$
$$\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;=ax+by+cz+\lambda (x^2+y^2+z^2-1)$$
$$\nabla_{x,y,z,\lambda} \mathcal{L}(x,y,z,\lambda)=(\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial x},\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial y},\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial z},\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \lambda})$$
$$\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;=(a+2\lambda x,b+2\lambda y,c+2\lambda z,x^2+y^2+z^2-1)$$
And therefore:

$$\nabla_{x,y,z,\lambda} \mathcal{L}(x,y,z,\lambda)=0$$
$$\iff$$
$$a+2\lambda x=0$$
$$b+2\lambda y=0$$
$$c+2\lambda z=0$$
$$x^2+y^2+z^2-1=0$$

However I don't know how to continue,since solving the first three equations for the variables $x,y,z$ respectively does not let us to to solve the last equation just for a single variable $\lambda$,can someone helps me to finish the question?

Comment: Note that the last equation is $... = 1$ and not $0$. It seems easy to solve it in $\lambda$. You are very near the solution

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track. If you solve the first three equations for $x,y$, and $z$ and substitute them into the fourth equation, you can solve for $\lambda$. Once you know $\lambda$, you can determine $x,y$, and $z$ from the first, second, and third equation, respectively.

Comment: Substitute back into the three equations: one of them is $a + 2 \lambda x = 0$.

Comment: Notice that you've already deduced $x = -a/2\lambda$, etc., so all you have to do is plug in $\lambda$. The two solutions for $\lambda$ give two solutions $(x,y,z)$ for the system. One will be your min and one will be your max.

Comment: $a^2, b^2$ and $c^2$ are always positive, so the second point will be your max and the first will be your min.